# R expand.grid with row restrictions

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, subset-sum

I have a numeric vector x of length N and would like to create a vector of the within-set sums of all of the following sets: any possible combination of the x elements with at most M elements in each combination. I put together a slow iterative approach; what I am looking for here is a way without using any loops.

Consider the approach I have been taking, in the following example with N=5 and M=4

```
M <- 4
x <- 11:15
y <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1), length(x))))
result <- y[rowSums(y) <= M, ] %*% x
```

However, as N gets large (above 22 for me), the expand.grid output becomes too big and gives an error (replace x above with x <- 11:55 to observe this). Ideally there would be an expand.grid function that permits restrictions on the rows before constructing the full matrix, which (at least for what I want) would keep the matrix size within memory limits.

Is there a way to achieve this without causing problems for large N?

Comment: Is the `11:15` token data (per @EtienneMoerman's optimization) or typical real data? What's the application of this? It's kind of rare to handle a cardinality of 2^45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
c(0, unlist(lapply(1:M, function(k) colSums(combn(x, k)))))
```

It generates the same result as with your expand.grid approach, shown below for the test data.

```
M <- 4
x <- 11:15

# expand.grid approach
y <- as.matrix(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1), length(x))))
result <- y[rowSums(y) <= M, ] %*% x

# combn approach
result1 <- c(0, unlist(lapply(1:M, function(k) colSums(combn(x, k)))))

all(sort(result[,1]) == sort(result1))
# [1] TRUE
```

This should be fast (it takes 0.227577 secs on my machine, with N=22, M=4):

```
x <- 1:22 # N = 22
M <- 4
c(0, unlist(lapply(1:M, function(k) colSums(combn(x, k)))))
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22  3  4  5  6  7
```

you may want to choose the unique values of the sums with

```
unique(c(0, unlist(lapply(1:M, function(k) colSums(combn(x, k))))))
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I should have mentioned that it'd also be useful to keep track of which elements are in each sum, but I can achieve that by working off your solution -- putting some more lines in your function and using combn again to create a matrix of element positions.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has to do with the sheer amount of combinations.
What you appear to be doing is listing all different combinations of 0's and 1's in a sequence of length of x.

In your example x has length 5 and you have 2^5=32 combinations
When x has length 22 you have 2^22=4194304 combinations.

Couldn't you use a binary encoding instead? 
In your case that would mean 
0 stands for 00000
1 stands for 00001
2 stands for 00010
3 stands for 00011
...

It will not solve your problem completely, but you should be able to get a bit further than now.